# Using json.Unmarshal gives ParseError when trying to convert unix formatted string into time.Time

Tags: json, go

I have a `JSON` file with following content:

```
{  ...
   "body": "{\"timestampFrom\":\"154087600\"}"
   ...
}
```

When I try to execute:

```
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(apiGatewayEvent.Body), &config); err != nil {
            glog.Errorf("Error occurred while trying to unmarshal body of APIGatewayProxyRequest. Error message - %v", err)
            return nil, err
        }
```

I receive:

> Error occurred while trying to unmarshal body of APIGatewayProxyRequest.
>
> Error message - parsing time ""1540857600"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse "857600"" as "-"

Thing is that I always will receive UNIX formatted input and I need to convert it to `time.Time`. How do I exactly do that?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to include all the code.  You are calling time.Parse and you should be calling time.Unix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your own time type and make that implement json.Unmarshaller, e.g. something like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

var data = []byte(`{"timestamp": 1562764768}`)

type myTime time.Time

func (mt *myTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    timestamp, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(b), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *mt = myTime(time.Unix(timestamp, 0))
    return nil
}

func (mt *myTime) String() string {
    return time.Time(*mt).String()
}

type body struct {
    Timestamp *myTime `json:"timestamp"`
}

func main() {
    var b body
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/zb6lQP361J5)